# amCharts - amMap Home Button Method

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, ammap

I am creating an amMap through amCharts http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap and it comes with its own home button which you can click and reverts to the map default.

I would like to do this externally through my own button, but can't quite find the methods that amCharts uses to achieve this.

A few methods I've used are:
chart.zoomTo(), chart.zoomToLongLat(), chart.zoomToXY() using the correct values of when the chart is initialized.  This works fine when the chart is not resized ever, but when the chart is resized (not re-initialized), those values become undependable, yet the home button is still able to bring me back to the default zoom.

**What method does this home button use? Or I can use to replicate what the home button does?**

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `zoomToLongLat` and pass in your map object's `initialZoomLevel`, `initialZoomLongitude` and `initialZoomLatitude`. From the [demo on AmChart's knowledge base](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-external-controls-zoom-map/) for its custom external home button:

```
function centerMap() {
  map.zoomToLongLat(map.initialZoomLevel, map.initialZoomLongitude, map.initialZoomLatitude);
}
```

You can resize the frame on the codepen demo to see that it resets itself correctly each time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. it very simple,

I did it this way:

```
map.addListener("rendered", function(event) {
      var map = event.chart;
      map.initialZoomLevel = map.zoomLevel();
      map.initialZoomLatitude = map.zoomLatitude();
      map.initialZoomLongitude = map.zoomLongitude();
});

function centerMap() {
  map.zoomToLongLat(map.initialZoomLevel, map.initialZoomLongitude, map.initialZoomLatitude);
}
```

```
<div onclick="centerMap();" class="icon-home"></div>
```